# Run a specific suite again before any failed tests with Protractor flake

Tags: typescript, protractor

I want to use Protractor Flake for the tests that failed. This is working but I have a specfile that needs to be run again before the failed tests start their second run. 
This specfile did not go wrong, but I need it as a test setup in my second or third run.

How can I tell Flake it needs to run that passed specfile again aswell?

Answer (score 0):

you probably should move your initialization code to the `beforeAll` function:

```
/* recommended */
describe('when the user Teddy B is created', function(){

beforeAll(function() { 
      ...
   });
   ...
}
```

https://www.protractortest.org/#/style-guide

---

creating dependencies between the tests is generally considered bad because it **prevents your tests from running in parallel**

Comment: But I have multiple spec files and I only want this spec file to run once. The tests do not need to run in parallel

Comment: I'm not allowed and I also think it's not necessary. I want to know how I can tell Protractor Flake to run a suite before it starts the failed tests.

Comment: provide a [mcve] then. generally speaking unit tests should not have pre-conditions that are not satisfied in their initialization phase. So whatever you are doing in there to rectify the failed test - that should probably be done somewhere else.